# TwinHelix IE PNG Fix not working for unordered list or list items

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, png, iepngfix

I am using the TwinHelix IE PNG Fix http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/ in order to have PNG transparency support in IE, but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to work in IE 6 for unordered lists and list items. Everything else works fantastic. Has anyone experienced this issue before, and did you find a fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out with this fix there is a list of tags that you need to add to the selector behavior that states what tags can accept the PNG background. These are within the script tag that goes into the header.